# I can't match the domain with the S3 buket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to use AWS S3 with GoDaddy Domain

My domain name is already taken by some bucket that is not mine. To match the domain with the S3. I have read that it must have the same names (the bucket and the domain).

I've been hours with this but I could not find the solution

So, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you saying that somebody else has a bucket with *exactly* the same name, such as `www.matias.com`?

Comment: Yes this is the case

Comment: It is unusual that somebody would have a bucket named the same as a domain name *you* own, including things like `www` and `.com`. Feel free to raise a Support request with AWS, including proof of ownership of the domain, requesting them to make the bucket name available to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS CloudFront infront of S3 and add the CName mapping for CloudFront instead of S3, using AWS Route53 or Godaddy domain mappings.